# Questionnaire tables

Tags: database-design

i will create a multi page questionnaire. I will have one record in all tables for each person who fills out the questionnaire. and all tables will hold the answers. The type of answers will be Yes/No/UK, multiple choice, fill-in-the-blank, comments etc.

tblDoctors
DoctorID- pk
Adress
name
Age

tblPatients
PatientID - pk
Gender
name
Age

tblQuestionnaire this is the table that will store the answers to the survey questions
questionnaireID pk
AnswerID fk
DoctorID fk 
PatientID fk
questionnaireTitle
QuestionnaireDate

tblQuestions
QuestionID - pk
QuestionText

tblAnswers 
AnswerID PK
AnswerText - 
PatientID- fk
QuestionID - fk

Am i in the right way To have for each patient results will be in one tuple?? And how to consider pages in questionnaire?? any ideas,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CANDY, this is what you've described as your current model:

[image: Existing ERD]

... but this is probably more like what you want:

[image: Proposed ERD]

In your current design, `tblQuestionnaire` has a FK to `tblAnswers`.  I don't think that makes sense.  Your questionnaire table should not be about the answers, it should be a heading for a series of connected questions.

Based on your question about handling pages, I've redefined your tables so that a `questionnaire` has one or more `page`s and each `page` has one or more `question`s.  For each `question` there are one or more possible `answer_choice`s.  These answer choices could be multiple choice options or they could be flags or codes that indicate to your system what kind of controls to present to the user to collect a typed-in answer - e.g. single line text box/multi-line text box, how many characters max, etc.  When a `patient` fills out a survey, they either pick one of the `answer_choice`s or they fill out some details - either way, the answer is recorded in the `patient_answer` table.